# Nexthink remote action powershell as admin

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, administrator, nexthink

I work as IT in a company and from to time we get a list of a bunch of computers that we need to run a bat or cmd file inside as admin to fix few things. The list is huge and remote connecting takes long time and disturbs the user.

We have nexthink software that allow us to run powershell command on target computer. The issue is I need the bat or cmd to run as admin.

I have tried doing -v runAs but this shows a pop up and asks the user to fill the admin credentials which he doesnt know.

2nd thing I tried is

```
$passwd = Convert-SecureString -String "adminpassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential './adminusername',$passwd

Start-Process cmd -Cred $cred
```

This one actually checks if the cred is wrong or not and opens cmd but when i run net session to verify if its running elavated I am getting access is denied.

Comment: Does Nexthink not have the option to run the script as the System account? Seems crazy if not. Having credentials in plain text in a script should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: I found the option to run script as the system account, however when I do that cmd is not opening infront of me but its showing as success in remote action log

Comment: Yeh its running as System you wont be able to see it, it should still perform the script though as long as it doesnt require any user interaction

Comment: I will change the powershell so that it copies a file from one folder to another. So if I find the copy in the other older that mean it does work

Comment: You are right it worked. I remember seeing the option before but because cmd wasnt showing up I thought it didnt work. Thanks for reminding me to test it out again. Post an answer so I can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nexthink itself should have an option to run the script as System, the script will be hidden in the background when it runs, because its running as system, but it should work all the same, so long as the script doesn't require user interaction.

Its always best to avoid having a password in a script at all costs.